# Readr::read_tsv() working for one txt file, but not for the (identitical) other?

Tags: r, csv, readr

I am trying use `read_tsv()` to load in my data into R like this:

```
dat <- read_tsv("output.txt")
```

I've used the same function for tab-separated text files before and it worked just fine. This time however I'm getting the following error:

```
Parsed with column specification:
cols(
  col_logical(),
  `_1` = col_logical(),
  `_2` = col_logical(),
  `_3` = col_logical(),
  `_4` = col_logical(),
  `_5` = col_logical(),
  `_6` = col_logical(),
  `_7` = col_logical(),
  `_8` = col_logical(),
  `_9` = col_logical(),
  `_10` = col_logical(),
  `_11` = col_logical()
)
Warning: 448 parsing failures.
row col           expected    actual         file
  1     1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE           'deneme.txt'
  1  -- 12 columns         1 columns 'deneme.txt'
  2     1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE           'deneme.txt'
  2  _1 1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE           'deneme.txt'
  2  _2 1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE           'deneme.txt'
... ... .................. ......... ............
See problems(...) for more details.

Warning message:
Duplicated column names deduplicated: '' => '_1' [2], '' => '_2' [3], '' => '_3' [4], '' => '_4' [5], '' => '_5' [6], '' => '_6' [7], '' => '_7' [8], '' => '_8' [9], '' => '_9' [10], '' => '_10' [11], '' => '_11' [12]
```

Which is obviously not working, but not working in a strange way I don't understand. It thinks there are 11 columns, when there is 12. Then, it fails to guess the correct data type (none of them are logical), which it successfully could before! I am including an example dataset that worked with `read_tsv()` before and an example dataset that is not working right now.

This is the example data that didn't work:

```
ovsm1_adami_aldatti_kadin_2a_05 adam    1   1   239.85434301424775  --undefined--   247.7376112047195   235.3560147034298   52.05022323524527   6.5499112757148295  55.65949698112956   0.08126228269085413
ovsm1_adami_aldatti_kadin_2a_05 adam    1   2   244.8835520848779   1.4564070245792597  246.82072176997366  243.70359367821465  64.89187579458462   2.1641176020019386  66.88747347027808   

0.08126228269085413
ovsm1_adami_aldatti_kadin_2a_05 adam    1   3   261.5729831605207   41.85930844916797   307.1142693228187   204.36913741336025  64.89187579458462   1.2151362742415437  61.957796034834814  

0.08126228269085413
ovsm1_adami_aldatti_kadin_2a_05 i   2   1   166.22560617807903  --undefined--   204.36913741336025  151.99560810090307  63.11853517394699   --undefined--   63.54749436042272   0.2603628117913832
ovsm1_adami_aldatti_kadin_2a_05 i   2   2   151.5917235900652   --undefined--   151.99560810090307  151.1878390792273   63.78952447455676   --undefined--   63.8658531351568    0.2603628117913832
ovsm1_adami_aldatti_kadin_2a_05 i   2   3   194.42181693674587  --undefined--   241.71658370470496  133.73542865220801  63.78952447455676   --undefined--   64.20475934014964   0.2603628117913832
ovsm1_adami_aldatti_kadin_2a_05 aldat   3   1   262.8748473239633   25.96753914339153   307.20648672837325  238.5251389434482   66.66386883205  1.4649381878481265  68.28592866615767   0.41604686318972034
ovsm1_adami_aldatti_kadin_2a_05 aldat   3   2   240.1288558709347   4.340209556654576   244.20543055789503  235.79454784524034  58.28521765232964   5.75233546883736    62.85806413243511   

0.41604686318972034
ovsm1_adami_aldatti_kadin_2a_05 aldat   3   3   243.40106390906058  2.0057544696869543  244.93290262696132  241.07738646120566  58.28521765232964   11.47909682502898   62.307285139208574  

0.41604686318972034
ovsm1_adami_aldatti_kadin_2a_05 ti  4   1   --undefined--   --undefined--   --undefined--   --undefined--   35.761099547455565  1.0017991871649559  35.200858427407184  0.7000302343159486
ovsm1_adami_aldatti_kadin_2a_05 ti  4   2   --undefined--   --undefined--   --undefined--   --undefined--   43.39233384796458   2.461654789948961   44.797095277535874  0.7000302343159486
ovsm1_adami_aldatti_kadin_2a_05 ti  4   3   --undefined--   --undefined--   --undefined--   --undefined--   43.39233384796458   1.5866872677343318  42.0051005461374    0.7000302343159486
ovsm1_adami_aldatti_kadin_2a_05 kadin   5   1   225.2816396620663   --undefined--   225.92521370361135  222.91796772766446  47.58943608188635   6.558659128476658   53.23731630459665   0.8870294784580498
ovsm1_adami_aldatti_kadin_2a_05 kadin   5   2   213.50307273189148  9.815765419804642   222.91796772766446  195.3915292510744   48.803239148178186  6.2908212606955916  54.46476384096549   

0.8870294784580498
ovsm1_adami_aldatti_kadin_2a_05 kadin   5   3   194.48213136593407  0.7021069213634096  195.3915292510744   193.97185882759527  48.803239148178186  0.8647268899860352  46.46325708290779   

0.8870294784580498
ovsm1_aslani_farketti_zebra_2a_09   aslan   1   1   185.06203630746313  3.0069371384674346  187.99581838427886  181.98692793330403  52.22509773118971   5.3966524703478 56.09242035734275   

0.1256084656084656
ovsm1_aslani_farketti_zebra_2a_09   aslan   1   2   200.04479355019342  --undefined--   200.04479355019342  200.04479355019342  43.79895997909392   4.207566032378694   46.61999480251702   

0.1256084656084656
ovsm1_aslani_farketti_zebra_2a_09   aslan   1   3   204.8645621866751   5.164766914157635   212.83049249499618  200.04479355019342  43.79895997909392   1.8605349885564046  52.344312104474156  

0.1256084656084656
ovsm1_aslani_farketti_zebra_2a_09   i   2   1   213.22057211800305  --undefined--   213.61065174100995  212.83049249499618  47.014841486812955  --undefined--   46.36188846231947   0.38925170068027215
ovsm1_aslani_farketti_zebra_2a_09   i   2   2   214.00073136401681  --undefined--   214.39081098702368  213.61065174100995  45.312184769532934  --undefined--   46.25970753246626   0.38925170068027215
ovsm1_aslani_farketti_zebra_2a_09   i   2   3   215.28052779011452  --undefined--   216.17390493884704  214.39081098702368  45.312184769532934  --undefined--   43.26751661234397   0.38925170068027215
ovsm1_aslani_farketti_zebra_2a_09   farket  3   1   203.4524841321715   13.02287342953739   217.9883871067541   191.76848637183997  48.075301545190676  7.678678001355539   52.961210239177575  

0.562857142857143
ovsm1_aslani_farketti_zebra_2a_09   farket  3   2   191.54198199571675  0.6629050380820111  192.2667554528704   190.6990271670027   49.94781556089073   9.344765523013207   54.70386015525213   

0.562857142857143
ovsm1_aslani_farketti_zebra_2a_09   farket  3   3   166.67471907673996  2.7120805688608813  169.2595643602701   163.85118175698642  49.94781556089073   12.00717880033682   50.014609942160256  

0.562857142857143
ovsm1_aslani_farketti_zebra_2a_09   ti  4   1   --undefined--   --undefined--   --undefined--   --undefined--   19.953680817791607  0.5673981502076435  20.277130388296754  0.8903099017384732
ovsm1_aslani_farketti_zebra_2a_09   ti  4   2   --undefined--   --undefined--   --undefined--   --undefined--   24.042946776686932  2.565586747107994   25.848757636861166  0.8903099017384732
ovsm1_aslani_farketti_zebra_2a_09   ti  4   3   --undefined--   --undefined--   --undefined--   --undefined--   24.042946776686932  1.9264697112352631  31.2719825242349    0.8903099017384732
ovsm1_aslani_farketti_zebra_2a_09   zebra   5   1   161.7417580823549   2.079841825255008   163.27478185517484  157.88807315194387  41.92516442972372   5.809893957726305   47.23632116085485   

1.0846182917611489
ovsm1_aslani_farketti_zebra_2a_09   zebra   5   2   152.21416609249926  2.970678492911428   157.88807315194387  150.31651324857864  41.56347538469716   6.965679368576994   44.8215467918196    

1.0846182917611489
ovsm1_aslani_farketti_zebra_2a_09   zebra   5   3   75.52172005509577   0.08920499095075367 75.58479750911273   75.45864260107881   41.56347538469716   4.551521119599394   41.90632850358233   

1.0846182917611489
ovsm1_baskani_kurtardi_bakan_2c_01  baskan  1   1   240.76895527350814  1.5696547946572375  242.503316946734    239.44591440988654  56.403026798058214  2.23519960665316    58.5770781416923    

0.11944066515495087
ovsm1_baskani_kurtardi_bakan_2c_01  baskan  1   2   258.61023079686254  --undefined--   258.7950547842763   257.8006696215377   50.082422888701785  3.9480395401208708  52.60495753461821   

0.11944066515495087
ovsm1_baskani_kurtardi_bakan_2c_01  baskan  1   3   251.2679829640712   4.14451945597683    257.8006696215377   246.40835145753346  50.082422888701785  1.7915834521264493  62.28480855329315   

0.11944066515495087
```

And this is the example data that `read_tsv()` successfully loaded with no problems whatsoever:

```
ovsm1_adami_aldatti_kadin_2a_05 9   0.4 0.45    --undefined--   --undefined--   --undefined--   --undefined--   --undefined--
ovsm1_adami_aldatti_kadin_2a_05 10  0.45    0.5 --undefined--   --undefined--   --undefined--   --undefined--   --undefined--
ovsm1_adami_aldatti_kadin_2a_05 11  0.5 0.55    --undefined--   --undefined--   --undefined--   --undefined--   --undefined--
ovsm1_adami_aldatti_kadin_2a_05 12  0.55    0.6000000000000001  --undefined--   --undefined--   --undefined--   --undefined--   --undefined--
ovsm1_adami_aldatti_kadin_2a_05 13  0.6000000000000001  0.6500000000000001  233.86893970704796  233.86893970704799  233.86893970704799  --undefined--   --undefined--
ovsm1_adami_aldatti_kadin_2a_05 14  0.65    0.7000000000000001  234.24005566263858  233.86893970704799  234.85594376542952  0.5595983208963401  0.3956957674464077
ovsm1_adami_aldatti_kadin_2a_05 15  0.7000000000000001  0.7500000000000001  235.9879740218075   234.85594376542952  241.32094897195597  4.176501029868071   2.953232199852312
ovsm1_adami_aldatti_kadin_2a_05 16  0.75    0.8 244.75133379179994  241.32094897195594  247.30132784643698  3.556196511848743   2.5146106687601923
ovsm1_adami_aldatti_kadin_2a_05 17  0.8 0.8500000000000001  245.49460060262726  243.6665144874841   250.39140474206968  3.7390266816142006  2.6438911216068353
ovsm1_adami_aldatti_kadin_2a_05 18  0.8500000000000001  0.9000000000000001  264.48847476991347  250.39140474206968  288.1600613822647   19.401877001123214  13.71919879524154
ovsm1_adami_aldatti_kadin_2a_05 19  0.9 0.9500000000000001  301.9497823905812   288.1600613822647   304.6781451710905   10.767522125987322  7.6137879118618255
ovsm1_adami_aldatti_kadin_2a_05 20  0.9500000000000001  1   294.00877104330345  281.75464754519567  302.23539630709365  --undefined--   --undefined--
ovsm1_adami_aldatti_kadin_2a_05 21  1   1.05    267.1116914771332   252.4266779707776   281.75464754519567  14.597373365551347  10.321901694293253
ovsm1_adami_aldatti_kadin_2a_05 22  1.05    1.1 242.68837776772395  237.53600386597762  252.4266779707776   --undefined--   --undefined--
ovsm1_adami_aldatti_kadin_2a_05 23  1.1 1.1500000000000001  236.84062256860992  234.55206240291247  241.12565737547783  3.7347359713544623  2.640857131286068
ovsm1_adami_aldatti_kadin_2a_05 24  1.1500000000000001  1.2000000000000002  244.14092895237954  241.12565737547783  246.51029185839977  3.2868834353701843  2.3241775661199924
ovsm1_adami_aldatti_kadin_2a_05 25  1.2000000000000002  1.2500000000000002  244.42961650562458  243.78693176718346  245.14105774643633  0.9219975654378295  0.6519507307585768
ovsm1_adami_aldatti_kadin_2a_05 26  1.25    1.3 243.4631249982616   243.2572947348176   244.11500512007814  --undefined--   --undefined--
```

I can't see a difference between the two datasets, they are both tab separated. Why does `read_tsv()` work for one but not for the other?

Comment: just try with `data.table::fread` then you may build as `tible`.
`df <- data.table::fread('file.tsv', sep = "\t") %>% as_tible()`

Comment: Which package is this from ?

Comment: `data.table`, you may call the function from package `data.table::fread()` or load the package `require(data.table)` or `library(data.table` then call the function only using `fread()`

Comment: check the `dput` and `structure` of the file which problem. I think You have some problem with the "\t"